# mysql get last values grouped

Tags: mysql, sql, limit

i have a table like this

```
id  orderid type  date
20  831     1   2016-10-26 15:09:25
22  1410    1   2016-10-26 15:09:27
23  1779    1   2016-10-10 15:09:29
26  1779    2   2016-10-10 15:09:29
24  1809    1   2016-10-26 15:09:30
```

and i want to get from every order the last type. So order 1779 should be type 2

can someone help plz?

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1):

In case you mean last type is the type with largest value, The query is just simple like this

```
SELECT orderid, 
    MAX(type) AS last_type
FROM table_name
GROUP BY orderid;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT id,orderid,type,date 
  FROM
     (
       SELECT *,
              ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY orderid ORDER BY type DESC ) AS rn
         FROM yourtable
      ) 
 WHERE rn = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT distinct t1.orderid , (select max(type) from table where orderid=t1.orderid)   from table t1

Try this